# Windows 2012 R2 RDS - can't change Connection Broker DNS round robin name via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I'm running into an issue when setting up a Windows 2012 R2 RDS Farm.  I mistakenly set up my High Availability Connection Broker's DNS round robin name to something that didn't match my cert.  I found a way to easily change the DNS name here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215484.aspx using the PowerShell cmdlet **Set-RDClientAccessName**.  When searching online I can see that a lot of people are having success using that cmdlet, but I am not.  Here's the error I'm receiving:

> PS C:\Users\root> Set-RDClientAccessName -ConnectionBroker "FMS-RDSBROKER01.blah.local" -ClientAccessName rds.bar.com
>
> Set-RDClientAccessName : The RD Connection Broker server is not available. Verify that you can connect to the RD
>   Connection Broker server.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-RDClientAccessName -ConnectionBroker "FMS-RDSBROKER01.foo.com" -Clien ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Set-RDClientAccessName

I'm not sure why this keeps failing.  This command is being run from the Connection Broker itself by by a domain admin (the same one who has been setting up the RDS farm from ground zero).  I also cannot suvessfully run that command from the other Connection Broker, nor any other server in the farm.   I'm also certain that I have the module installed to enable that cmdlet:

> PS C:\Users\root> Get-Module -Name RemoteDesktop -ListAvailable
>
> Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
>
> ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
>   ---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
>   Manifest   2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop                       {Get-RDCertificate, Set-RDCertificate, >New-RDCertificate, ...

If anyone has any troubleshooting steps I'd appreciate it.  I am worried that the dash in the hostname is a problem, but I tried single and double quotes to attempt to rule that out.  I'm also not a Powershell buff so I'm not certain what steps are advised after that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, and it's painfully aggravating that I missed this- I wasn't running Powershell as an administrator.  Correcting that oversight allowed me to fun the command successfully.

Thank you to everyone who viewed this.